# Where does Debian (Ubuntu) store key mappings?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I've just replaced my Debian installation with Ubuntu today. In my old setup, I configured the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to work as another <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, but I can't remember how exactly I did it before. However it got carried over to my new installation because I have my separate `/home` partition preserved between installations. I just want to know how that happened. Where in `/home` can I find the configuration that enabled the setup to get carried over to my new setup? In addition, how do I set it up to work that way for another account in my computer?

Comment: Do you mean on the console or in a particular desktop environment?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to answer that question because I'm not very familiar with how mapping keys work.

Comment: well then you question cannot be answered, except by arbitrarily picking one of the methods or all of the methods and describing them. It would really help if you could find out whether you are running, say, KDE or GNOME etc ...

Comment: I was running Gnome on my old Debian environment, and if I'm not mistaken the default one in Ubuntu (Unity?) is a Gnome derivative. I seem to recall doing the bindings through `gconf-editor` but my memory is kind of hazy.

Comment: I suppose if you want a global setup, you might try editing `/etc/default/keyboard` - the setting you want is either `XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:swapcaps"` or `XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"`. `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` will be necessary most likely after that. Another thing you may try is adding something like `setxkbmap -option 'ctrl:swapcaps'` (or `nocaps`) in one of your initialization files (say `.xinitrc`, `.bashrc` or just anything suitable) or as a startup command in GUI (now this depends on what you use, Unity, Gnome Shell etc., but should be available just anywhere).